# Telegram Bots API has different entities for the same message

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

What could be the reason that the Telegram Bots API returns different entities for the same messages, but from different platforms?

Message:
`hello ||world||`

Result Telegram iPhone:
`"text":"hello world", "entities":[{"offset":5,"length":6,"type":"spoiler"}]`

Result Telegram Desktop (Mac OS):
`"text":"hello world", "entities":[{"offset":6,"length":5,"type":"spoiler"}]`

Unclear...

I expect the same entities everywhere with the same message, but for some reason they are different.